# After uploading a SNAPSHOT and putting as dependency seems empty

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus, snapshot

We have a few modules in a Gradle project. Once we upload one module as a snapshot to our Maven repo, it uploads fine with no complaints from Maven.

However, when we go to our same project, and change our local module dependency to the snapshot one, it behaves like the Snapshot it downloaded was empty. It surely exposes its own `api` dependencies, but not the classes we wrote.

We've been uploading release modules in the past with no trouble like that. It seems like the moment we upload it to the snapshot server, everything gets messed up.

Is there anything we're (not) doing that we need to change?

Comment: So, is this Snapshot actually empty? Have you looked into the jar file whether the classes you desire are indeed there?

Comment: @JFMeier that's a good question. By chance do you know where they are downloaded? It's an Android project using Gradle, so I assume there's an external directory where they're downloaded